# Copy the value into another column if one column value matches to the condition, else paste the next matching value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, z-score

I want to copy the values from column A to column C only if the Z scores in column B are within the range of -2.68 and 2.68, and I do not want any empty cells in column C. I have tried filter formula, but giving an #CALC! error.  Column A values may vary so I want to read column till end of the row condition.

```
=FILTER(A2:A35,AND(B2:B35>-2.68,B2:B35<2.68))
```

| Time1 | Z score |  | Time2 | Z score |  | Time3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2812 | 3.508 |  | 1024 | 0.461 |  |  |
| 1024 | 0.461 |  | 1772 | 1.736 |  |  |
| 1772 | 1.736 |  | 343 | -0.699 |  |  |
| 343 | -0.699 |  | 436 | -0.541 |  |  |
| 436 | -0.541 |  | 419 | -0.570 |  |  |
| 419 | -0.570 |  | 245 | -0.866 |  |  |
| 245 | -0.866 |  | 287 | -0.795 |  |  |
| 2468 | 2.922 |  | 1312 | 0.952 |  |  |
| 287 | -0.795 |  | 894 | 0.240 |  |  |
| 1312 | 0.952 |  | 642 | -0.190 |  |  |
| 894 | 0.240 |  | 898 | 0.246 |  |  |
| 642 | -0.190 |  | 752 | -0.002 |  |  |
| 898 | 0.246 |  | 406 | -0.592 |  |  |
| 752 | -0.002 |  | 479 | -0.468 |  |  |
| 406 | -0.592 |  | 433 | -0.546 |  |  |
| 479 | -0.468 |  | 377 | -0.641 |  |  |
| 433 | -0.546 |  | 805 | 0.088 |  |  |
| 377 | -0.641 |  | 837 | 0.142 |  |  |
| 805 | 0.088 |  | 391 | -0.618 |  |  |
| 837 | 0.142 |  | 417 | -0.573 |  |  |
| 391 | -0.618 |  | 372 | -0.650 |  |  |
| 417 | -0.573 |  | 1279 | 0.896 |  |  |
| 372 | -0.650 |  | 453 | -0.512 |  |  |
| 1279 | 0.896 |  | 313 | -0.750 |  |  |
| 453 | -0.512 |  | 631 | -0.209 |  |  |
| 313 | -0.750 |  | 554 | -0.340 |  |  |
| 631 | -0.209 |  | 881 | 0.217 |  |  |
| 554 | -0.340 |  | 491 | -0.447 |  |  |
| 881 | 0.217 |  | 350 | -0.687 |  |  |
| 491 | -0.447 |  | 477 | -0.471 |  |  |
| 350 | -0.687 |  | 865 | 0.190 |  |  |
| 477 | -0.471 |  | 502 | -0.428 |  |  |
| 865 | 0.190 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 502 | -0.428 |  |  |  |  |  |

picture shows how the values required in next column skipping the unmatched values to the condition

[image]

After implement this formula

```
=FILTER(Table1,ABS(Table1[Z score])<2.68)
```

it is showing result as below in the picture. and a third column E is created, not about this.

[image: results image]

Comment: Is the table in columns A and B named Table1, or something else? If the output of the formula is 3 columns, then likely Table1 is some other table in your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiplication for `AND` logic in `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER(A2:B35,(B2:B35>-2.68)*(B2:B35<2.68))
```

[image]

Or use `ABS`:

```
=FILTER(A2:B35,ABS(B2:B35)<2.68)
```

[image]

Comment: This is giving #SPILL! error

Comment: Then remove the data below the cell that's blocking the spilling.

Comment: Can you suggest if I have to read values randomly in column A (instead of fixing A36) as total number rows may vary, then how to use the same formula?

Comment: Turn columns A and B into a table (Ctrl+T). Your resulting formula should look something like `=FILTER(Table1,ABS(Table1[Z score])<2.68)`.

Comment: I mean A2:B35 may vary as I paste these values some times it could A2:A10 or A2: A110, so after every paste I need to change these values in the provided formula, so can we automatically read the value till the end of the column?

Comment: A table automatically resizes to hold more data.

Comment: It picked random matching from column A values and copied in C

Comment: You may need to edit your question with a demonstration of how you implemented this formula - there's nothing "random" about the formula logic.

Comment: @RupeshNath how the given formula can go wrong, it clearly shows in the screenshot, it is working as expected and does match with the output you have shown in your post, to validate your statements you should update the OP.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - the expected out is to take on corresponding values in A column if B column value is in between -2.68 to 2.68, whereas the second formula considered A7 value and picked others.

Comment: As I have said in my previous comments formula is working, you need to see are you really referring to `Table 1`, because your present screenshot doesnt resembles with the original. For Example `419` is showing `-0.602` where it is `-0.570` Couldnt relate the column `D` values with `Table 1` `Z Score` Column. None of the values in column `D` are present in `Z Score` Column, click on any cell table structure and check design tab for the table name

Comment: It worked after I removed Table1 and selected the column A manually, which showed it is Table 7.  =FILTER(Table7[Time1],ABS(Table7[Z score])<2.68)  :)